Shopware 6 Property Option Entity Creation with '0'
I have created a custom Importer for Shopware 6.6, that creates property options on the fly.
$this->propertyGroupOptionRepository->create(
    [
        [
            'id' => $newUuid,
            'groupId' => $propertyGroupId,
            'name' => $name,
            'translations' => $translations,
        ],
    ],
    $context,
);

I have noticed, that when my property option value is '0', it is being created as null. How do I make sure to get the proper '0' value in the database instead of null?
My translations variable looks like this:
array (
  'en-GB' => 
  array (
    'name' => '0',
  ),
  'de-DE' => 
  array (
    'name' => '0',
  ),
  'zh-CN' => 
  array (
    'name' => '0',
  ),
)

It does not matter if I fetch the data using DAL or SQL, the stored value is null.

I have some question - can you update the question? What's the Shopware version? Where exactly are you seeing the null ? In a database query do you fetch via the repo? What's the $context? Is it for sure working with '1' ? Then it really might be a bug.

I tried running with the exact data you gave, and it works as expected when saving with value '0' instead of null in both DB or selecting with DAL. The Version is shopware 6.6.8.2.
I can't find exactly if there is a ticket fix issue for this or not. I suggest you upgrade to the latest version, currently 6.6.9.0, and try again. If you still have the problem, try investigating whether installed plugins are affected.
